# IF or IFS google sheet array formula

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, array-formulas

My array formula needs to be updated to include another if statement.

The original formula, works great:
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(((O2:O<TODAY())*(I2:I<>"Delivered"))>0," Past due","⚫ On track"))
Translates to: If task due date is less than today and the status is not equal to delivered, then past due, else on track.

I now need the formula to read: If task due date is less than today and the status is not delivered, then "past due" OR if task due date is blank and status is equal to not started, then leave the cell blank.

I am not sure if I should be using IF or IFS.

My attempt at re-writing the formula is below.

=ARRAYFORMULA(IFS(((O2:O<TODAY())*(I2:I<>"Delivered"))>0," Past due",[(O2:O=""())*(I2:I<>"Not Started"))>0,""]))

Basically the task is either past due or the cell should be blank or if this is even possible.

[spreadsheet image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aokeH.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IFS is not supported under arrayformula properly. use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
 IF((O2:O<TODAY())*(I2:I<>"Delivered"), " Past due", 
 IF((O2:O="")*(I2:I<>"Not Started"), "", )))
```

[image]

### update

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
 IF((O2:O="")*(I2:I="Not Started"), "", 
 IF((O2:O<TODAY())*(I2:I<>"Delivered"), " Past due", )))
```

Comment: returned an error "Wrong number of arguments to IF. Expected between 2 and 3 arguments, but got 4 arguments."

Comment: the sheet is public now

Comment: "Not Started" is still showing as past due...which was my original problem. The "Past Due" condition is the problem I think because the "Not Started" tasks still meet that condition

Comment: I think the equation needs an "OR" or "+" somewhere.

Comment: try: `=ARRAYFORMULA(
 IF((O2:O="")*(I2:I="Not Started"), "", 
 IF((O2:O<TODAY())*(I2:I<>"Delivered"), " Past due", )))`